Subordonnée introduite par que et une préposition
J'aimerais savoir laquelle des deux phrases suivantes est correcte/mieux?


Nous pouvons profiter de que notre prof est malade aujourd'hui.
Nous pouvons profiter du fait que notre prof est malade aujourd'hui.


La question est bien sûr plus générale. Comment traiter une subordonnée introduite par que après une préposition ? Est-ce que j'ai toujours besoin de quelque chose comme du fait ?
Autre question: Une subordonnée peut-elle aussi être le sujet d'une phrase comme dans l'exemple suivant ?

Que tu es malade ne m'intéresse pas.

Ou je dois dire


Je ne m'intéresse pas à que tu es malade.
Je ne m'intéresse pas au fait que tu es malade.


Merci beaucoup pour toutes vos réponses!

Des trois phrases que tu proposes dans ta deuxième question seule la première est correcte (Que tu es malade ne m'intéresse pas). Je pense que la plupart des gens mettraient le subjonctif (Que tu sois malade ne m'intéresse pas) mais Le bon usage précise que dans cette construction l'indicatif peut être employé pour souligner la réalité du fait. Par contre il faut le subjonctif dans la phrase : Je ne m'intéresse pas au fait que tu sois malade. L'emploi du subjonctif nécessite une autre question (une seule question par « question »)

Oui une subordonnée peut être sujet (on appelle ça une subordonnée substantive) mais c'est une autre question.... Un « sujet » par question.

On ne peut pas écrire Nous pouvons profiter de que notre prof est malade aujourd'hui. Il est possible d'employer du fait que comme tu le proposes, cependant je pense que le plus courant (stylistiquement moins lourd à mon avis) serait l'emploi de de ce que :

Nous pouvons profiter de ce que notre prof est malade aujourd'hui (pour aller nous promener).

Quand le verbe est suivi d'une préposition on n'emploie pas que tout seul  mais  de ce que ou à ce que.

Nos parents tiennent à ce que nous fassions nos devoirs.
Réjouissez-vous de ce que votre professeur ne soit jamais malade.
Pourquoi ne pas profiter de ce que vous êtes riches ? (V. Hugo)

Par contre la construction du verbe avec la préposition ne s'impose pas toujours. On pourra dire aussi bien :

Je m'étonne que ton professeur soit absent.
Je m'étonne de ce que ton professeur soit absent.

Dans le cas du verbe profiter on peut souvent entendre (et lire parfois aussi) les deux mais beaucoup de grammaires considèrent que seul l'emploi avec   de ce que est correct :

La constr. profiter que (pour profiter de ce que) est incorrecte mais fréq. dans la lang. pop.  (TLFi)


Profiter de ce que (+ indicatif) : je vais profiter de ce que je suis en vacances pour me reposer.
recommandation :
Éviter profiter que.  (Larousse)

Le bon usage (Grevisse) consacre trois pages aux constructions des subordonnées complétives avec à ce que et de ce que. On trouvera sur la BDL une page consacrée à ce sujet : Subordonnée complétive introduite par que, à ce que et de ce que, et cette autre page, sur le site Richesse et difficultés de la langue française,  qui montre que la question est parfois discutée entre spécialistes, peut aussi être une aide À ce que / De ce que.

Dans la langue parlée, "Nous pouvons profiter que notre prof est malade" est aussi usité que critiqué.

Quelle horreur ;-)

@Frank ???? C'est quoi qui t'horrifie comme ça ? Quelle grosse horreur ai-je bien pu écrire ?

@None Je profite que Frank n'est pas là ;-) Je soupçonne qu'il a oublié d'adresser son commentaire à François Jurain.

@jlliagre Effectivement :-) Oui, c'est Nous pouvons profiter que notre prof est malade que je trouve horrible, pas ta réponse, None. Je pense que j'ai été traumatisé par un prof de français il y a très longtemps qui tenait les que pour un élément de mauvais style, alors un que tout nu et mis en relief comme ça dans profiter que, je trouve cela horrible hahaha.
